# Checking to see if money value is between a range of other money value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a pretty basic question, but everything that I searched via SQL and MONEY datatype is all about casting and adding characters.

I have two values that I am looking at; PAYMENT and OWED. Both are money datatypes in my server. The PAYMENT is positive, and the OWED is negative. I am looking to see if (based on other criteria i have figured out) if the PAYMENT is within +/- $10 of the owed. This will be in the WHERE clause

When the PAYMENT equals the OWED, I can do this in the where clause

```
  WHERE PAYMENT = (OWED*-1)
```

What I am trying to do is simply

```
 WHERE PAYMENT BETWEEN ((OWED*-1)+10) AND ((OWED*-1)-10)
```

This is returning NULLs when I pull the data

All help is appreciated!

Edit: Adding sample data

```
  select
  pay.clientID
 ,pay.payment_amount
 ,pay.paydate
 ,ow.owed_amount

  from paymenttable pay
  join owingtable   ow on pay.clientID = ow.clientID


  where 1=1
  AND pay.paydate > '1/1/2017'
  AND pay.payment_amount BETWEEN ((ow.owed_amount*-1)+10) AND 
  ((ow.owed_amount*-1)-10)
```

Comment: Please can you post some data so we can see what is held within the Table? This will help us answer your question.

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected output from it.

Comment: What's wrong with `WHERE PAYMENT BETWEEN (OWED-10) AND (OWED + 10)` ?

Comment: Change left and right sides of the BETWEEN operator. The smaller value must be the first there

Comment: Holy crap, something really simple. It was the right and left sides of the between operator

Comment: I would suggest not using between. It can be truly evil. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 1):

Better do it like below :

```
WHERE PAYMENT BETWEEN (abs(OWED) - 10) AND (abs(OWED) + 10)
```

As you know already perhaps, `BETWEEN` works with `MIN ans MAX` and left part must be the `MIN` value.

Comment: Please consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting an answer rewards the contributor and helps others to find a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

BETWEEN operators were on the wrong sides....